# Install and using liquidjs with html

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, node-modules, liquid

I am trying to install and use liquid, but I am totally new to it and after a lot of searching, haven't found any good tutorial, about a basic setup of a liquid project.
I have managed to set up the project with npm.

I am reading everywhere this:

```
import { Liquid } from "liquidjs";
const engine = new Liquid();

engine.parseAndRender("{{name | capitalize}}", { name: "alice" }).then(console.log); // outputs 'Alice'
```

But nowhere is been explained what this does, and how to use it.

after copying and pasting this in the index.js and in the html file linking to this file doesn't reflect liquid.

I have added this to the package.json:
`"type": "module"`,

Can anyone help, how to use liquid that reflect in my index.html

Thanks,
E.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What does this code do: Exactly as the comment says: It prints `Alice` to the console ...

Comment: I am trying to get this working:  <div>{{ page.title }}</div> in my html. So when I put a this tag in a html file and preview it in the browser, to see the page title.

Answer (score 0):

I use Vue.js with liquidjs. I have created a little module that load a liquid template and affect the text to my vue data "text".

```
// MyComponent.vue
<script setup>
  import { liquidLoader } from './liquid-loader.js'
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import textFile from './text-file.txt'

  const text = ref('');

  onMounted(() => liquidLoader(text, textFile));
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Super title</h1>
  <p>{{ text }}</p>
</template>
```

liquid-loader is in charge to create engine and call the template

```
// liquid-loader.js
import { Liquid } from 'liquidjs';

export async function liquidLoader(vueData, file, params = {}) {
  const engine = new Liquid();

  await engine.renderFile(file, params).then(function(text) {
    vueData.value = text;
  }.bind(vueData));
}
```